# JMeter - Handling websocket response with alternating binary and text frames

Tags: websocket, jmeter

I have a web socket single write sampler followed by a web socket single read sampler in a while loop.
The challenge I am facing is that

This is how my test plan looks currently.

```
Thread Group
  \_ Web socket open connection
  \_ Web socket single write sampler
  \_ While controller-1
      \_ Web socket single read sampler-1 (text response filter)
  \_ While controller-2
      \_ Web socket single read sampler-2 (binary response filter)
  \_ While controller-3
      \_ Web socket single read sampler-3 (text response filter)
  \_ While controller-4
      \_ Web socket single read sampler-4 (binary response filter)
```

The thread errors out in case there is a text response coming in after the last binary response filter.
Any help on how to handle this scenario is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error? And do i understand correctly that you get 4 responses that are handled properly, but the that first re-iteration of the loop gets the error?

Comment: @Peter I have 4 while controllers and each while controller has a single read sampler as a child. The first and third single read samplers have text response filter and the second and fourth have binary response filter (I have edited the test plan to make it clearer). I don't have the exact error message handy as all my servers are down for the weekend, but it is in the lines of "text response received while expecting binary response." I will update you with the exact error message as soon as I am able to connect back to my servers. And thanks for the great work on the web socket samplers :)

Comment: The "text / binary" dropdown in the read sampler UI is not a filter; it is stating what kind of message the sampler should expect and parse. So apparently (given the error message about expecting binary), your testplan is not exactly matching the communication pattern the server is using....

Comment: @Peter Thanks for your response. I understand what you are saying. But my question is,  how to handle in such a situation where I cannot predict the order of text/binary messages returned by the server.

Comment: Checkout version 1.2.8 of the plugin: i added an option that the read sampler can receive text _or_ binary; does that solve your issue? https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/issues/168/add-option-to-single-read-sampler-to-read

Comment: Yes, the new version of the plugin solves my issue. Thanks Peter, your help is really appreciated! Could you please add the comment as a response? I will mark it as the correct answer.

Comment:  Actually, your question made me realise that the read sampler was more restrictive then necessary, so it was good feedback.

Comment: Thank you! Glad I could be of some help. Once again, thanks for the excellent work on the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout version 1.2.8 of the plugin: this version adds an option so that the read sampler can receive text *or* binary (i.e. you don't have to specify upfront which data frame it should expect). https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/issues/168/add-option-to-single-read-sampler-to-read